# Static class methods overloads use cause a compiler error

Tags: c#, .net

I have a problem using static class method overloads (not sure if it reproduces on non-static classes)

I have 3 projects. The are in ref chan like project-1 references project-2, project-3 references project-2. That means project-3 dont have direct project-1 reference.

On the project-2 i have a static class that contains method with two overloads: one have a parameter of string, and one - the type from project-1. When im trying to call method from project-3 using overload with string param, the compiler raise an error that i must reference project-1 in project 3. If i create a new method and do the same as overloaded method with string param - everythig works fine. I'll try to explain in code.

Project-1

```
public class Foo
{
   public string Text { get; set; }
   public string Bar()
   {
      return Text + " bar";
   }
}
```

Project-2 (references Project-1)

```
public static class StaticClass
{
   public static string RunAnother(string str)
   {
      var foo = new Foo { Text = str };
      return Run(foo);
   }

   public static string Run (string str)
   {
      var foo = new Foo { Text = str };
      return Run(foo);
   }

   public static string Run(Foo foo)
   {
      return foo.Bar();
   }
}
```

Project-3 (References ONLY project-2)

```
var t1 = StaticClass.Run("test"); //Compile error: " The type 'Foo' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced."

var t2 = StaticClass.RunAnother("test"); //Works great
```

Why is it so?

Comment: Have you rebuilt your complete solution?

Comment: @FrodeNilsen Yes. Its not a runtime error. It's compiler error.

Comment: How can something work that hasn't been built?
The first line in your Project-3 example doesn't use the Foo type.

Comment: Okay. I'll correct myself: if i use var t1 = StaticClass.Run("test"); - i have comiler error. If i use var t2 = StaticClass.RunAnother("test"); - build pass fine and it works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the compiler resolves the overload that is to be called, it analyzes the parameter types and their relations. E.g. you could have overloads for the following situation where the compiler needs to select the right overload:

```
public class MyBase { }
public class MyClass : MyBase { }

public class A
{
  public void DoSomething(MyBase b) { }
  public void DoSomething(MyClass c) { }
}
```

Therefore, the compiler and later the .NET runtime needs to know details about the types that are involved in the overloaded methods. This is why project-3 needs a reference to project-1. By the way, this problem is not related to static classes.

So either you add a reference from project-3 to project-1 or you replace `Foo` with a type that project-3 and project-2 know. You could use the following options:

- Move `Foo` to another project that is referenced by all three projects.
- Define a `FooAdapter` in project-2 and use this as parameter. So only project-2 knows of the original `Foo`, but project-3 does not know it.

Answer (score 0):

For parameter resolution the compiler has to know each overloaded method, also the ones that aren't used in the end.
Eg. maybe there are some implicit conversion operations that should come into play.